# Why are the top voted answers on top of the accepted answer when it was answered by the asker?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

Why is it that the top voted answer always appears on top if the accepted answer is created by the asker himself? Usually if the answer is accepted by the asker, it worked for him, so why wouldn't that be on top in this situation?

Comment: Is this because you answerd your own question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/963667/how-can-i-change-the-font-of-the-top-bar-without-changing-the-shell-theme?answertab=votes#tab-top Don't put the accept in too high regaurd, it only means that it helped to OP the most, NOT that it is best. Highly voted answers are often better ones and people should not overlook votes for the accept, answers should help anyone who reads them. As this happened only an hour ago, wait for votes.

Comment: @MarkKirby Isn't that the answer rather than a comment to the question?

Comment: @MarkKirby we are waiting for that answer!

Comment: @MarkKirby But I think OP has a valid point here. I would expect a uniform behaviour in this scenario. What could be the rationale behind placing the accepted answers at the top when they're posted by others but not when posted by the askers themselves? In both the cases there's a chance of having another answer with higher score than that of the accepted answer.

Comment: Loosely related to [On what basis is the position of an answer decided?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16956/on-what-basis-is-the-position-of-an-answer-decided)

Answer (score 2):

From [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235):

> ### Can I accept my own self-answer?
>
> Yes; if you've self-answered your own question, you can mark your answer as the accepted answer. There are some differences, though, that exist in order to ensure everyone gets a fair shot at answering:
>
> - Accepting your own answer won't award you any reputation.
> - The question must be at least 48 hours old before you can accept a self-answer.
> - Self-answers that are accepted will never be pinned to the top.

"**Self-answers that are accepted will never be pinned to the top.**"

This rule stays intact though there has been a recent change in the way answers are pinned (read this for more information: [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568)).

This rule also applies to Ask Ubuntu Meta (read this for more information: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19793).