# Why does it take a couple of days before you can answer your own question?

Tags: discussion

Why is it that if I ask a question, and then find the answer the next day, I still have to wait one more day before I can mark my answer as solved?

Wouldn't it be more productive to just let people mark it as solved so others don't waste their time on it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can answer immediately, you just can't accept it. Accepting is not very important. It doesn't indicate much, only that the OP considered this the best answer. As far as the system is concerned, questions are counted as answered if they have at least one answer with a positive score.

As for why the wait, it is probably just to let others also answer. The accept mark makes no difference to the system, but human psychology is another thing. Often, seeing an accepted answer will deter others from posting their own. Making you wait might just be a mechanism to allow the community to also contribute to your question.

Comment: And there is the fact that an accepted answer, is alway on top even if you sort by votes. So that wait time gives you time to see if someone else answered and maybe even consider this answer a better fit to accept above your own.

Comment: @Videonauth But if OP accepts their own answer it [won't be at the top](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17350/why-are-the-top-voted-answers-on-top-of-the-accepted-answer-when-it-was-answered).

Comment: Weird and on other questions the accepted answer staying on top no matter if there are more up-voted answers, just because the  answer is accepted but not from the OP.